# How to encode list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I retrieve information from the web site using beautiful soup and I want to store these values ​​in a single csv file row so i store this information in a list and later I store this list in the file. The problem is that I doesn't  handle special characters.

```
#Répartition des prix moyen au m²
Repartition=[]          
Inferieur=soup.find_all("text", {"class" : "p6_segmentMainLabel-outer"})
Superieur=soup.find_all("text", {"class" : "p6_segmentValue-outer"})
for Data in list(zip(Inferieur,Superieur)):
    try:
        Inferieur,Superieur = Data
        Inferieur=Inferieur.string.encode('utf-8')
        Superieur=Superieur.string.encode('utf-8') 
        Data2=' = '.join([Inferieur,Superieur])
        print Data2
        Repartition.append(Data2)
    except NavigableString: 
            pass
```

After execution of the code I get :

> Supérieur à 12.27 €/m² = 14 
>   Inférieur à 12.27 €/m² = 14

here is the result in the csv file

> ['Sup\xc3\xa9rieur \xc3\xa0 12.27 \xe2\x82\xac/m\xc2\xb2 = 14',
>   'Inf\xc3\xa9rieur \xc3\xa0 12.27 \xe2\x82\xac/m\xc2\xb2 = 14']

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: That's the expected output since you are encoding to utf8. What is your question here? And how do you write to the csv. That seems to be missing from the code in your question. [mcve]

Comment: Works fine for me...Can you post the code that you use to write to csv?

Answer (score 0):

If you want csv output, you should have a look at the `csv` module - https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.writer.

Here's an example (taken from the Python docs and modified for your example):

```
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    w = csv.writer(csvfile, quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(Repartition)
```